# ExpandableListView множественный выбор

Tags: android, expandablelistview

как реализовать множественный выбор для ExpandableListView?

Answer (score 0):

`ExpandableListView` является потомком стандартного класса `ListView`, соответственно к нему применимы стандартные:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Comment: я сделал так, проблема в том, что при нажатий на элемент галочка не ставится, вот мой код ...

Comment: может я что то делаю неправильно ?

Answer (score 0):

Мой код activity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    ExpandableListView elvMain;
    AdapterHelper ah;

    SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter;
    TextView tvInfo;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
        // создаем адаптер
        ah = new AdapterHelper(this);
        adapter = ah.getAdapter();

        elvMain = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.elvMain);
        elvMain.setChoiceMode(ExpandableListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        elvMain.setAdapter(adapter);

        // нажатие на элемент
        elvMain.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition,   int childPosition, long id) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onChildClick groupPosition = " + groupPosition +
                        " childPosition = " + childPosition +
                        " id = " + id);
                tvInfo.setText(ah.getGroupChildText(groupPosition, childPosition));
                return false;
            }
        });

        // нажатие на группу
        elvMain.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onGroupClick groupPosition = " + groupPosition +
                        " id = " + id);
                // блокируем дальнейшую обработку события для группы с позицией 1
                if (groupPosition == 1) return true;

                return false;
            }
        });

        // сворачивание группы
        elvMain.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onGroupCollapse groupPosition = " + groupPosition);
                tvInfo.setText("Свернули " + ah.getGroupText(groupPosition));
            }
        });

        // разворачивание группы
        elvMain.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onGroupExpand groupPosition = " + groupPosition);
                tvInfo.setText("Развернули " + ah.getGroupText(groupPosition));
            }
        });

        // разворачиваем группу с позицией 2
        elvMain.expandGroup(2);
    }
```

код Адаптера

```
package com.example.excryptocurrencyexpandablelistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter;

public class AdapterHelper {

    final String ATTR_GROUP_NAME= "groupName";
    final String ATTR_PHONE_NAME= "phoneName";


    // названия компаний (групп)
    String[] groups = new String[] {"HTC", "Samsung", "LG"};

    // названия телефонов (элементов)
    String[] phonesHTC = new String[] {"Sensation", "Desire", "Wildfire", "Hero"};
    String[] phonesSams = new String[] {"Galaxy S II", "Galaxy Nexus", "Wave"};
    String[] phonesLG = new String[] {"Optimus", "Optimus Link", "Optimus Black", "Optimus One"};

    // коллекция для групп
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> groupData;

    // коллекция для элементов одной группы
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> childDataItem;

    // общая коллекция для коллекций элементов
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> childData;
    // в итоге получится childData = ArrayList<childDataItem>
    // список аттрибутов группы или элемента
    Map<String, String> m;
    Context ctx;
    AdapterHelper(Context _ctx) {
        ctx = _ctx;
    }

    SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter;

    SimpleExpandableListAdapter getAdapter() {
        // заполняем коллекцию групп из массива с названиями групп
        groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String group : groups) {
            // заполняем список аттрибутов для каждой группы
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put(ATTR_GROUP_NAME, group); // имя компании
            groupData.add(m);
        }
        // список аттрибутов групп для чтения
        String groupFrom[] = new String[] {ATTR_GROUP_NAME};
        // список ID view-элементов, в которые будет помещены аттрибуты групп
        int groupTo[] = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
        // создаем коллекцию для коллекций элементов
        childData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>>();

        // создаем коллекцию элементов для первой группы
        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        // заполняем список аттрибутов для каждого элемента
        for (String phone : phonesHTC) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put(ATTR_PHONE_NAME, phone); // название телефона
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        // добавляем в коллекцию коллекций
        childData.add(childDataItem);
        // создаем коллекцию элементов для второй группы
        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone : phonesSams) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put(ATTR_PHONE_NAME, phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);

        // создаем коллекцию элементов для третьей группы
        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone : phonesLG) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put(ATTR_PHONE_NAME, phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);
        // список аттрибутов элементов для чтения
        String childFrom[] = new String[] {ATTR_PHONE_NAME};
        // список ID view-элементов, в которые будет помещены аттрибуты элементов
        int childTo[] = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};

        adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                ctx,
                groupData,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                groupFrom,
                groupTo,
                childData,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                childFrom,
                childTo);
        return adapter;
    }

    String getGroupText(int groupPos) {
        return ((Map<String,String>)(adapter.getGroup(groupPos))).get(ATTR_GROUP_NAME);
    }

    String getChildText(int groupPos, int childPos) {
        return ((Map<String,String>)(adapter.getChild(groupPos, childPos))).get(ATTR_PHONE_NAME);
    }

    String getGroupChildText(int groupPos, int childPos) {
        return getGroupText(groupPos) + " " +  getChildText(groupPos, childPos);
    }
}
```

не получается ставить галочки в чекбоксах 
[image: полученный ExpanDableListView]